# Storage management in a mobile application

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I need some help and tips in how to manage information  storage of an application.

I want to develop a mobile application (using Xamarin platform) that contains a lot of information. What are my options to manage this information for each client? Should I work only with database that the usage will be integrated in my application (connection through the "client side" application, and live update)? Or Should I develop a "Server Side" part in which all the data will be managed?

If I need to choose the "Server Side" option, how should I do it in C#?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer the question as to how to manage data - wether to keep everything on the app or offload to the server.

The key things to think about are data storage capabilities, cell phone network data usage, the types of data you're talking about and how fast and frequently it should be available.

For example, if you have a ton of text stuff, even if it's offloaded to a server it's pretty static so it's probably fast to load off a server and won't drain your user's network data usage and battery at that versus if you're talking downloading media (pics / video / music) you are going to face some serious needs.

1. What kind of information are you talking about - text, images, video etc
2. How much information are you talking about?
3. What information is necessary to keep available in the app at all times
4. What information will be frequently accessed by the user
5. How big is this data - is the user OK with you spending their data usage to get a LOT of stuff off the server

So here's 2 ultimate bits of advice, firstly learn about using a webservice in your app:

1. Figure out how to use a web service in your app just to download/upload text - this will show you how data can be downloaded/uploaded to a server
2. Repeat step 1 with an image - this will show you how media can be uploaded/downloaded

Secondly for your app, think through your data requirements and now that you have an understanding of how to offload stuff to a server you can better weigh your pros and cons towards in app or on server data storage or a combo.